# Negative exponent of exponent in cyclic group of prime power order.

Tags: exponentiation, cyclic-groups

Given a cyclic group $G$ of order $|G| = p^s$, we have that $x^{p^s} = e$ for all $x\in G$.
Consider then $x^{p^{s-t}}$:
$$
x^{p^{s-t}} = x^{p^sp^{-t}} = \left(x^{p^s}\right)^{p^{-t}} = e^{p^{-t}} = e
$$
This result is of course invalid ($s=t$ implies $x=e$ for all $x$), but what step is false? And is there a way to interpret $x^{p^{-t}}$?

Comment: As you have noticed, $g$ to a fractional power has no apparent meaning for a general group element.

Comment: @lulu So the $p^{t-s}\overset!= p^tp^{-s}$ step is false?

Comment: Well, I'd prefer to locate the flaw in the step  $x^{p^sp^{-t}} = \left(x^{p^s}\right)^{p^{-t}}$ since the left hand is defined and the right hand is not.

Comment: You can have only that $x^{p^s}=x$ for all $x\inG$ (an example is $G=\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p}$ that has order $p$ and for the little Fermat theorem $x^p=x$ for all $x\in G$).